# Using $_Request inside function PHP

Tags: php, function, session, request

**1)**

I have this:

```
function ObtainRequest($Field, $Method) {
  $Returned = "";
  if ($Method == "POST")
    $Returned = $_POST[$Field];
  else if ($Method == "GET")
    $Returned = $_GET[$Field];
  else
    $Returned = $_REQUEST[$Field];
return $Returned;
}
```

Now, using the function:

```
if (isset(ObtainRequest("OneField","POST"))) {
  DoSomething();
} else if (!isset(ObtainRequest("OneField","POST"))) {
  DoOtherthing();
}
```

But my script isn't running (**SHOWING PLANK PAGE**)...

What's my mistake?

**2)**

The `$_REQUEST` is lost inside of function?

This code works!!:

```
      if (isset($_REQUEST["OneField"])) {
        DoSomething();
      }
```

This code doesn't work!!:

```
      if (isset(ObtainRequest("OneField","REQUEST"))) {
        DoSomething();
      }
```

This code doesn't work!!:

```
      if (empty(ObtainRequest("OneField","REQUEST"))) {
        DoSomething();
      }
```

**3)**

Is it applicable to Session too?

Comment: I fix my question, If $Field is equal to "Get" or "Post" the return must be $_REQUEST[]...

Comment: `empty(ObtainRequest("OneField","REQUEST"))` failing, because `empty()` and `isset()` can not be used with expressions. They might be used just with variables. That's why `isset($_REQUEST["OneField"])` works properly.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is here:

```
$Method == "Post"
```

But you passing uppercased `POST`:

```
ObtainRequest("OneField","POST")
```

Fix with [`strtoupper()`](http://php.net/strtoupper):

```
function ObtainRequest($Field, $Method) {
  $Returned = "";
  $Method = strtoupper($Method);
  if ($Method == "POST")
    $Returned = isset($_POST[$Field]) ? $_POST[$Field] : false;
  else if ($Method == "GET")
    $Returned = isset($_GET[$Field]) ? $_GET[$Field] : false;
  else
    $Returned = isset($_REQUEST[$Field]) ? $_REQUEST[$Field] : false;
  return $Returned;
}
```

---

Also, this function might be shortened with [`switch`](http://php.net/switch) construction:

```
function ObtainRequest($Field, $Method) {
    switch(strtoupper($Method)){
        case "POST": return isset($_POST[$Field]) ? $_POST[$Field] : false;
        case "GET": return isset($_GET[$Field]) ? $_GET[$Field] : false;
        default: return isset($_REQUEST[$Field]) ? $_REQUEST[$Field] : false;
    }
}
```

---

Second problem is that [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset) might be used with **variables**, *but not with function results*. Use boolean check instead:

```
if (ObtainRequest("OneField","POST") !== false) {
  DoSomething();
} else if (ObtainRequest("OneField","POST") === false) {
  DoOtherthing();
}
```

---

> Is it applicable to Session too?

Well, if you interested in my opinion: *I **would not** mix* [`$_SESSION`](http://php.net/%24_SESSION) *in such function* with [`$_POST`](http://php.net/%24_POST), [`$_GET`](http://php.net/%24_GET) and [`$_REQUEST`](http://php.net/%24_REQUEST), because [`$_SESSION`](http://php.net/%24_SESSION)s meaning is different. Also, it exists differently, not like them.

However something like this function might be realized for [`$_SESSION`](http://php.net/%24_SESSION) itself.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem which I can see that you are using post instead of POST...

yes you can do this with sessions too, but codes need to be modified a bit..